# pager Cannot resolved as a variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to make action bar tabs, but I got a error:"pager Cannot resolved as a variable..."
Thansk for your help.

Java code;

```
package olcay.akgn.fibonaccicalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener {

android.app.ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
   viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    actionBar=getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Hesaplayıcı");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);


    Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Bölünme");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);






    }

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.d("AKGN","onTabReselected at "+" position"+tab.getPosition()+"name"+tab.getText());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.d("AKGN","onTabReselected at "+" position"+tab.getPosition()+"name"+tab.getText());

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.d("AKGN","onTabReselected at "+" position"+tab.getPosition()+"name"+tab.getText());

    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter

{

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    Fragment fragment=null;
    if(arg0==0){
        fragment=new Hesapla(); 
    }   

    if(arg0==0){
        fragment=new Bolunme (); 
    }   
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}







}
```

Note; I begin this project with this video tutorial;
           https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEl0ylVvZho

I tried to "Create "pager" in type id " but it did not solved my issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a `ViewPager` widget on your activity_main layout.

Never edit the R class - it is automatically generated.

Comment: How to do this? Thanks for your help

Comment: Here are an example of how to declare the ViewPager on your XML: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#views
Good luck!